# My android location service killed when app switched to background

Tags: android, android-location

Please apologize me if my question is repeated or simple. Struggling in this issue for a long time.

I need to track user's location even when my app is switched to background. On surfing I found that the location processor code can be written as a service, so that the service will not be killed and we can get the user's location (in both status - app in foreground and when app runs in background).

When my app is in foreground, I was able to track user's location continuously. However, when I switched the app to background, I feel my location service dies and I was not able to track user's location. Please find my code below:

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testmylocation"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".MyService"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.testmylocation;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.Window;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class)); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**MyService.java**:

```
package com.example.testmylocation;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyService extends Service
{
    private static final String TAG = "TestMyLocation";
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 0;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 0;
    long itsBatchId = 0;

    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener
    {
        Location mLastLocation;
        public LocationListener(String provider)
        {
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {        
            Thread aThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sendLocationValues(location);
                }
            });
            aThread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);            
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }
    } 

    private void sendLocationValues(Location theLocation) 
    {
        //A web service will be called and the user's current location will be stored in server
    }

    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] 
    {
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);       
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        initializeLocationManager();    
        itsLocationHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
    }

    private Handler itsLocationHandler = new Handler() 
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message theMessage) 
        {
            if(theMessage.what == 1)
            {
                try 
                {
                    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE, mLocationListeners[1]);
                } 
                catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) 
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
                } 
                catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) 
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    } 

    private void initializeLocationManager() 
    {
        if (mLocationManager == null) 
        {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please correct what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need continuous tracking of the user or can you do it at intervals?

Comment: I can track location it at intervals too.. Just for testing purpose I have used LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListeners[1]);

Comment: Please gent auto start permission in chines devices

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Android 4.0, the OS has gotten much more agressive about killing off unnecessary processes. If you need to track the user's location even when your app is in the background, then you need to declare your service as a foreground service. This raises the priority of your service so that Android is unlikely to kill it unless it really needs the resources. See [Running a service in the foreground](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) for details about how to do this.

Comment: I tried with startForeground() and now my location service seems to be running properly in background. Thank you. However, on investigating the received location coordinates, I found that, sometimes the location coordinates are not properly captured. There are few  time gaps where there is no location capture. I am sure that my service is seems to be running properly (able to see my app icon in notification bar). How can I further tweak my location service, so that there is no time gaps (app background) and I receive location in regular intervals. Please help, thanks again for your help.

Comment: There is no guarantee that you get callbacks at regular intervals. The parameters that you pass to `requestLocationUpdates()` are just **hints**. Each manufacturer implements this code themselves and they all need to make tradeoffs between performance, accuracy and battery life. The only thing I can suggest is to get a wakelock so that the phone will never go to sleep while you are expecting locations. This may be one factor that influences the callback frequency. Realize that, if you do this, it will have significant negative impact on the battery life.

Answer (score 2):

> location processor code can be written as a service, so that the service will **not** be killed

There is nothing can guarntee that the service will never be killed, however you can increase the likelihood that your service will continue running by obtaining [`WakeLock`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) and start it as [`Foreground service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)

I would recommend you check few open source projects such as [Open GPS Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/open-gpstracker/) and [Traceper](http://code.google.com/p/traceper/)

Comment: I tried with startForeground() and now my location service seems to be running properly in background. Thank you. However, on investigating the received location coordinates, I found that, sometimes the location coordinates are not properly captured. There are few  time gaps where there is no location capture. I am sure that my service is seems to be running properly (able to see my app icon in notification bar). How can I further tweak my location service, so that there is no time gaps (app background) and I receive location in regular intervals. Please help, thanks again for your help.